# Including JSP expression inside value of html opion tag

Tags: java, html, list, jsp, drop-down-menu

I am trying to dynamically show options in an html select element, using jsp. The code that follows isn't working though, and i am not sure as to why:

```
<select class="form-control" name="department">
      <option selected>-- Please choose a department --</option>
      <% for (int i=0; i <departments.size(); i++) {%>
      <%! int index = departments.index0f(department) + 1;%>
      <option value="<%=index%>"><%=department.getName()%></option>
      <%}%>
```

departments is a list of Department type objects, created earlier in the document. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: this part inside the for loop looks completely wrong,`<%! int index = departments.index0f(department) + 1;%>`, it is trying to create a instance variable `index` with each iteration, which i don't think would work

Comment: What is `department`? at some point you might have something like `departments.get(i);` stored in that variable.

Comment: Scriptlets are evil!  Use the JSTL - search for <c:forEach> examples.

Comment: @Ramanlfc This is my intention, i want in every iteration the value of the option to be the index of the item in the list + 1 (because the option with value = 0 is the default one ). Can you spot any syntax error in this?? Because i am not sure i can. I am a jsp beginner so i might be wrong, any input from you would be extremely helpful! :)

Comment: @OscarJara department is an element of the List <Department> departments